# Find out where PE file ends through PE header?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, portable-executable

I want to append some binary data to the end of my executable. This is just to make my program into a single file. I tried using UpdateResource but I hit some bug inside it with my specific data, so I have to use another solution. So I need to know the original file size to determine if there is actually any data appended to it. Is it possible to obtain this information from the PE headers?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I hit some bug inside it with my specific data"?  As far as I know UpdateResource just works with a binary blob of data, so the specifics of that data shouldn't matter.

Comment: `UpdateResource` _can_ work with binary blobs of data (type `RT_RCDATA`). However, if you pass something else, the specifics of the data _do_ matter. E.g. "All data containing strings or text must be in Unicode format." That suggests you may encounter a "bug" when it rejects your ASCII string.

Comment: That only applies if you are using one of the predefined data types that has string data.  RT_RCDATA is just a binary blob; Windows doesn't know or care what kind of data it contains.  As long as you serialize and deserialize it properly it will work fine.

Comment: I use RT_RCDATA, but when I add two of these they crash kernel32.dll. I am able to reproduce the crash with XN Resource Editor, so I count it as "external bug" and looking solution elsewhere...

Comment: It must be a bug with XN Resource Editor.  Is the data particularly large?  How is it structured?  I've used UpdateResource to add large (50+ MB) zip files as resources successfully, so I'm not sure why your data would be so special.  If you insist on going the PE route I would use a 3rd party library, as parsing PE files is fraught with peril.

Comment: google for "site:http://www.codeproject.com/ self extract", there are many implementations.

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution here http://www.strchr.com/creating_self-extracting_executables

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to, if you can get the size of each chunk. This may be of assistance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

Comment: I tried summing the size of each chunk and sometimes it almost works, sometimes it gives result which is double the file size.

Comment: Taking back the double file size thing. It was due to loading file at different path than I thought. You also need to add nt_header.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders to the calculation and then it seems to work for some files :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find this PE file reader useful. 
You should be able to extract the appropriate value from the PE header using this software.
Full source supplied.

http://www.objectmedia.ltd.uk/freeSoftware/peFileDLL.html

There is also a PE File Explorer (with source) on the same site. I can't post more than one URL at present because I don't have enough status points, so you'll have to work it out.

The PE File Explorer allows you to browse the contents of the PE file.

I wrote the software I am referring to (which in turn was inspired, many, many moons ago by a software tool by Matt Pietrek call LIPOsuction).