# Computing the size of an ELF file based on the header information

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, executable, elf

I understand it is possible to compute the size of an ELF file (i.e., where it ends) based on the [information found in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085563/find-where-32-bit-elf-linux-binary-ends-and-padding-begins) (i.e., `e_shoff + (e_shentsize * e_shnum)`), assuming that there is a section header table ("SHT"), and the SHT is the last part of the ELF.

However, SHT is not required to load the binary, and I was wondering wether it would be possible to compute the same information if the SHT was missing (e.g, an stripped binary). Can we leverage the program header or other offsets to compute the size programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we leverage the program header or other offsets?

The information that is required for the binary to start running is contained in program headers (use `readelf -Wl a.out` to see what's there).

You can compute the *minimum* required size of the binary by finding maximum value of `phdr->p_offset + phdr->p_filesz`. If you truncate the file at that size, it should continue to work (or at least load and reach `main`).

But the file may contain any number of additional non-loadable sections, so don't be surprised if the size you compute is smaller than the file size on disk.

Whether these additional sections are required or not depends entirely on the executable -- it may have code which `open`s `argv[0]`, `seek`s to some offset, and `read`s data from there (in which case the application will stop working after truncation).

P.S.

> assuming that ...the SHT is the last part of the ELF.

That assumption is not necessarily true, and is certainly not required for the file to be a proper `ELF` file.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I clarified my question a bit. My goal here is to do this programmatically and not through readelf. Any way you recommend to iterate through program headers to keep track of  `p_offset + phdr->p_filesz`?

Comment: @AshkanHosseini The answer is exactly the same -- you can read program headers programmatically (it's actually quite easy) , in _exactly_ the same way  `readelf` does. The offset and count are found in the ELF file header.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Yeah I will just use `e_phnum` and then index the information. It's impossible to get the exact size then? Estimate only?